# Pure rolling with two contact points

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

When a sphere is rolling on a sufficiently rough surface we use conditions such as
V= rω
But what conditions can we apply for a system where sphere is in contact with two points on the stationary frame?
e.g. ball purely rolling between two rods
Or ball rolling on ground while in contact with a wall **not slipping on either surface**. etc..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very well-posed. Just as an example $V=r\omega$ is quite rude: velocity, position and angular velocity are vectors; moreover, which point of the spere are you considering?

Anyway, to answer your question, it really depends on the relative position of the surfaces of contact with the sphere.

Anyway, to have a feasible motion you need to allow for **the spinning of the sphere around axis perpendicular to the contact surfaces**: I think this is the condition you're looking for. Just two examples:

- take a road with a V-section and use it as a slide for your sphere. It rolls, and if you look at each contact point, you can recognize the motion as the compostion of pure rotation and rotation around normal axes at contact points;
- extreme case: put a sphere between two flat parallel surfaces. If these surfaces are not moving, you can only spin the sphere around the axis perpendicular to the flat surfaces to avoid slip.